# Add new DAG to airflow scheduler

Tags: airflow, workflow, pipeline, directed-acyclic-graphs, orchestration

I ran airflow web server under one of my virtual environments (`myenv`). When I tried to add some new dummy DAGs, my result didn't go as I expected.

Here is the story:

First, I created a new DAG which is literally a copy of "example_bash_operator" with another dag_id. Then I put this dag under the same directory as other example days were, which is "~/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/example_dags". But when I opened the web server UI, this newly created dag wasn't shown.

I'm really confused. Should I change `AIRFLOW_HOME`? I did `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` as [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) indicates. What's more, why the example dags are collected under the virtual environment directory for site packages instead of the airflow home that I declared?

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='my_test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['some_tag'],
    params={"example_key": "example_value"},
) as dag
```

This is the only place that I changed from `example_bash_operator`.

Answer (score 1):

Example DAGS are just example DAGs - they are "hard-coded" in airflow installation and shown only when you enable them in config. And they are mostly there to be able to quickly see some examples.

Your own dags should be placed in ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags. not in example_dags folder. Airflow only scans regularly the DAGs folder for changes because it does not expect example dags to change. Ever. It's a strange idea to change data inside installed python package.

Just place your dag in ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags and if they will have no problems, they should be shown quickly. You can also disable examples in `airflow.cfg` and then you will have a cleaner list of only your dags from "dags" folder.

Comment: That makes sense though. Does it require us to create a folder called `dags`?